# Get exact Windows build in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to get the exact Windows build of my os in a batch-file and I want to store it as a variable. I need the full build like 14393.3144 (displayed if `winver` is used), because I want to check if  an update was successfully installed. I've already tryed using `wmic os get buildnumber` but it only returns 14393. Additionally to this I thought about reading the Windows Update log but creating it with the powershell command `Get-WindowsUpdateLog` simply takes to much time and isn't reliable enough.

Comment: What does `ver /r` disclose ?

Comment: @Marged - "The syntax of the command is incorrect", since `ver` doesn't have arguments.

Comment: `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v BuildLab`

Comment: @LotPings That's not exaclty what I'm looking for.. Does something in the returned string change, if I install a new patch like [this](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=4a96dbb7-bbf9-4813-9bfe-b84b252fcaa7) ? If yes I'm fine with it :)

Comment: To check if a specific HotFix/Update is installed use `powershell -c "Get-HotFix KB4512517"` I don't know and can't verifiy if that one changes the BuildLab.

Comment: What does `wmic OS get Version` return? Or `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Version:"`?

Comment: @somethingdark you are right, this is ancient syntax: http://www.mdgx.com/secrets.htm#VER

Comment: @LotPings ty, I will go the way, you've described. That one works for me.
@aschipfl `wmic os get version` returns `10.0.14393` and the other one works for a couple of seconds but returns nothing :(

Comment: Nothing? well, just try `systeminfo` then (no post-filtering of the locale-dependent output), so in the first few returned lines there should be some version information; the output contains all the installed hotfixes too...

Comment: yeah without any filters it return lots of information, including hotfixes

Comment: @aschipfl I use `systeminfo | findstr /l "KB4512517"` to check if the hotfix is installed now. TY :)

Comment: @LotPings `Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v BuildLabEx` works to get the exact os build. So your first suggestion was really close to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example which retrieves the full version using [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic):

```bat
@Set "OSVer="
@For /F EOL^=V %%A In ('"%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" OS Get Version 2^>NUL')Do @For %%B In (%%A)Do @Set "OSVer=%%B"
@Set OSVer 2>NUL&&Pause
```

On a test machine, this has just returned `10.0.18362`

---

You could of course use the internal `Ver` command, *(which technically returns the version of `cmd.exe`, not the OS)*:

```bat
@Set "OSVer="
@For /F Delims^=] %%A In ('Ver')Do @For %%B In (%%A)Do @Set "OSVer=%%B"
@Set OSVer 2>NUL&&Pause
```

On a test machine, this has just returned `10.0.18362.295`

---

You could of course try parsing the registry for the information too:

```bat
@Set "RKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
@For /F Tokens^=2* %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%RKey%" /V CurrentBuildNumber^" 2^>NUL')Do @Set "NUM=%%B"
@For /F Tokens^=2* %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%reg.exe" Query "%RKey%" /V UBR^" 2^>NUL')Do @Set /A UBR=%%B 2>NUL
@Echo(%NUM%.%UBR%&Pause
```

On a test machine, this has just returned `18362.295`

---

Alternatively, take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/q/963910) Super User question and answers.

Comment: just returns `OSVer=10.0.14393`, but I found another solution now

Comment: @Robin, please see my latest edit, which includes a registry based method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ver](https://ss64.com/nt/ver.html). 
The output is like what you want.

```
> C:\Users\user>ver
> 
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.678]
```

Comment: If I use `ver` I get `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]` as output.